# JWT authentication for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I'm trying to support JWT bearer token (JSON Web Token) in my web API application and I'm getting lost.

I see support for .NET Core and for OWIN applications.
I'm currently hosting my application in IIS.

How can I achieve this authentication module in my application? Is there any way I can use the `<authentication>` configuration similar to the way I use forms/Windows authentication?

Answer (score 805, accepted):

I answered this question: [How to secure an ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775594/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-web-api/11782361#11782361) 4 years ago using HMAC.

Now, lots of things changed in security, especially that JWT is getting popular. In this answer, I will try to explain how to use JWT in the simplest and basic way that I can, so we won't get lost from jungle of OWIN, Oauth2, ASP.NET Identity, etc..

If you don't know about JWT tokens, you need to take a look at:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

Basically, a JWT token looks like this:

```
<base64-encoded header>.<base64-encoded claims>.<base64-encoded signature>
```

Example:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImN1b25nIiwibmJmIjoxNDc3NTY1NzI0LCJleHAiOjE0Nzc1NjY5MjQsImlhdCI6MTQ3NzU2NTcyNH0.6MzD1VwA5AcOcajkFyKhLYybr3h13iZjDyHm9zysDFQ

A JWT token has three sections:

1. Header: JSON format which is encoded in Base64
2. Claims: JSON format which is encoded in Base64.
3. Signature: Created and signed based on Header and Claims which is encoded in Base64.

If you use the website [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) with the token above, you can decode the token and see it like below:

[image: A screenshot of jwt.io with the raw jwt source and the decoded JSON it represents]

Technically, JWT uses a signature which is signed from headers and claims with security algorithm specified in the headers (example: HMACSHA256). Therefore, JWT must be transferred over HTTPs if you store any sensitive information in its claims.

Now, in order to use JWT authentication, you don't really need an OWIN middleware if you have a legacy Web Api system. The simple concept is how to provide JWT token and how to validate the token when the request comes. That's it.

In the [demo I've created (github)](https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt), to keep the JWT token lightweight, I only store `username` and `expiration time`. But this way, you have to re-build new local identity (principal) to add more information like roles, if you want to do role authorization, etc. But, if you want to add more information into JWT, it's up to you: it's very flexible.

Instead of using OWIN middleware, you can simply provide a JWT token endpoint by using a controller action:

```cs
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    // This is naive endpoint for demo, it should use Basic authentication
    // to provide token or POST request
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string Get(string username, string password)
    {
        if (CheckUser(username, password))
        {
            return JwtManager.GenerateToken(username);
        }

        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    public bool CheckUser(string username, string password)
    {
        // should check in the database
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is a naive action; in production you should use a POST request or a Basic Authentication endpoint to provide the JWT token.

#### How to generate the token based on `username`?

You can use the NuGet package called `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` from Microsoft to generate the token, or even another package if you like. In the demo, I use `HMACSHA256` with `SymmetricKey`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Use the below code to generate symmetric Secret Key
///     var hmac = new HMACSHA256();
///     var key = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.Key);
/// </summary>
private const string Secret = "db3OIsj+BXE9NZDy0t8W3TcNekrF+2d/1sFnWG4HnV8TZY30iTOdtVWJG8abWvB1GlOgJuQZdcF2Luqm/hccMw==";

public static string GenerateToken(string username, int expireMinutes = 20)
{
    var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
        }),

        Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),
        
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), 
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);

    return token;
}
```

The endpoint to provide the JWT token is done.

#### How to validate the JWT when the request comes?

In the [demo](https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt), I have built
`JwtAuthenticationAttribute` which inherits from `IAuthenticationFilter` (more detail about authentication filter in [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)).

With this attribute, you can authenticate any action: you just have to put this attribute on that action.

```cs
public class ValueController : ApiController
{
    [JwtAuthentication]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

You can also use OWIN middleware or DelegateHander if you want to validate all incoming requests for your WebAPI (not specific to Controller or action)

Below is the core method from authentication filter:

```cs
private static bool ValidateToken(string token, out string username)
{
    username = null;

    var simplePrinciple = JwtManager.GetPrincipal(token);
    var identity = simplePrinciple.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    if (identity == null || !identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return false;

    var usernameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
    username = usernameClaim?.Value;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
       return false;

    // More validate to check whether username exists in system

    return true;
}

protected Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateJwtToken(string token)
{
    string username;

    if (ValidateToken(token, out username))
    {
        // based on username to get more information from database 
        // in order to build local identity
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            // Add more claims if needed: Roles, ...
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Jwt");
        IPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<IPrincipal>(null);
}
```

The workflow is to use the JWT library (NuGet package above) to validate the JWT token and then return back `ClaimsPrincipal`. You can perform more validation, like check whether user exists on your system, and add other custom validations if you want.

The code to validate JWT token and get principal back:

```cs
public static ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipal(string token)
{
    try
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;

        if (jwtToken == null)
            return null;

        var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey)
        };

        SecurityToken securityToken;
        var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

        return principal;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //should write log
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the JWT token is validated and the principal is returned, you should build a new local identity and put more information into it to check role authorization.

Remember to add `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` (default authorization) at global scope in order to prevent any anonymous request to your resources.

You can use Postman to test the [demo](https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt):

Request token (naive as I mentioned above, just for demo):

```
GET http://localhost:{port}/api/token?username=cuong&password=1
```

Put JWT token in the header for authorized request, example:

```
GET http://localhost:{port}/api/value

Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImN1b25nIiwibmJmIjoxNDc3NTY1MjU4LCJleHAiOjE0Nzc1NjY0NTgsImlhdCI6MTQ3NzU2NTI1OH0.dSwwufd4-gztkLpttZsZ1255oEzpWCJkayR_4yvNL1s
```

The demo can be found here: https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt

Comment: Well explained by @Cuong Le but i like to add more:

If you are using OWIN check the UseJwtBearerAuthentication available in Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt you can use this owin middleware on the WebAPI to validate every incoming request automatically. use the owin startup class to register the middleware

Comment: I've actually implemented in pretty much the same way after I found this:
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Your answer is excellent. +1 + accept on it.

I only have one open issue - Whats the best way to ping-pong (client-server) the bearer token? My client sends it - I go through the filter and either get a 401 or a valid authentication, do my stuff and want to set the token on the response. I can do it ugly with modifying the response header on the authentication filter, but is there a better way?

Comment: @AmirPopovich You don't need to set token on the response, token need to be stored somewhere else on the client side, for web, you can put in local storage, whenever you send HTTP request, put the token on the header.

Comment: @CuongLe Great post! I followed it step by step now I ran into problem that all my API methods are requesting for token, i.e. login, register and reset password. How do I add them to exception list? What could go wrong?

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, just realised that there is a attribute [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: @CuongLe Can I check on client-based? If I know the token, I can retrieve data from any client.

Comment: @NEER: Not sure that I understand your question but you can add client Id into the token

Comment: @CuongLe I give an example. Let's say we have two client computers (C1 and C2). I'm logged in with C1 and getting the token. Then I use C2 with token returning from c1. What I want to do is: If C2 is not logged in, C2 can not do anything. Can I make such a restriction?

Comment: @NEER: Well, you can put the computer's IP or (or name) into the token and from backend, you can filter based on this info

Comment: Instead of passing Username/Password to get a token, can't we generate an apikey ? what's the best way to generate it ?

Comment: Wow this is the most simple explication I have seen in a long time. +100 if I could

Comment: @Homam: Sorry fro this late answer, the best way to generate is: var `hmac = new HMACSHA256();var key = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.Key);`

Comment: @CuongLe: Thanks for this answer. It is brilliant. Just one question you are using expires in SecurityTokenDescriptor. What would happen after expiry time is passed? How would I generate new token?

Comment: @CuongLe - Regarding this ` public const string Secret = "856FECBA3B06519C8DDDBC80BB080553"; // your symetric`, what is the best way to generate and store the secret?

Comment: If I could up-vote this 1000 times I would. This is an amazingly good answer. Thank you!

Comment: Struggling at setting this up with the Authentications filter. I'm using ASP.NET Mvc though

Comment: @CuongLe I now manually installed WebApi in my Project and used a Web Api Controller and used the JwtAuthenticationAttribute on the methods. But still I can access them without a token. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @CuongLe With a separate Web Api project the opposite happens. I can't access the method (even with a valid token provided)

Comment: @CuongLe How to delete the JWT token on any function like sign out?

Comment: @DevSab JWT will be expired, so no need to delete it. The main point in here is we validate token on every request. If you need use provide Logout functionality, maybe you need to convert token to cookie local identity

Comment: @xaisoft: I updated the answer how to generate the secret

Comment: @TimLiberty: I think you need to call to the end point to get new token again

Comment: Thanks so much for this example, it really helped but I am hitting a stumbling block regarding refreshing the token, is there a good example following this pattern?

Comment: Thank you for the simple and concise example, yet extremely helpful

Comment: a really nice implementation step by step  at http://www.decatechlabs.com/how-to-secure-webapi-using-json-web-tokenjwt

Comment: Dear @CuongLe can you please elaborate your point here > This is naive action, in production you should use POST request or
> Basic Authentication endpoint to provide JWT token

Comment: This is a great explanation, can you do the same for RS256 and how to implement that from scratch?

Comment: just saying :`simplePrinciple?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;` since it can be null and hence exception....

Comment: @CuongLe - Is the secret key generated one time and then stored in a configuration or can it be generated every time a user logs in?

Comment: when we use JWT token then HMAC is not required? i heard HMAC prevent reply attack. so share your view. JWT token can prevent reply attack by hacker?

Comment: Great Answer. If anyone don't know how to call the autorized method, try this:
        HttpClient myclient = new HttpClient();
        myclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
    myclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", (token));

            string urlParameters = "";
        HttpResponseMessage response = myclient.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;

Comment: Token expiration did not work for me, to fix it i added
 ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
To the TokenValidationParameters

Comment: In production you will need some kind of refresh token mechanism. Care to add that to the above? Otherwise nice post!

Comment: private const string Secret = "db3OIsj+BXE9NZDy0t8W3TcNekrF+2d/1sFnWG4HnV8TZY30iTOdtVWJG8abWvB1GlOgJuQZdcF2Luqm/hccMw=="; you describe this line, but with this token generate  same value.

Comment: I opened a pull request on your code because I think I've found a bug when the Authorization header. If it's allright for you I suggest to edit this answer too!

Comment: Is it necessary to check username - generated from token - existence from database/any storage, whenever we send API request with token ?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, how do you create the secret key?

Comment: How do I set this up in a fake http context? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981426/how-do-i-mock-fake-the-session-object-in-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: https://jwt.io/ says your sample key above has an invalid signature. Any idea why?

Comment: @Imdad see the comment in the code "Use the below code to generate symmetric Secret Key"

Comment: Anyone using the demo code from CuongLe's repo will notice there is a bug where requests with no authorisation header are not handled, meaning any query without one can get through (not so secure an endpoint!). There is a pull request from @magicleon to fix this issue here: https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt/pull/4

Comment: @Bh00shan see the comment `// More validate to check whether username exists in system`

Comment: @cuongle I am not able to access the claim data in my controller. I tried a few different options and nothing is working for me. You can check the post here with what I tried [link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296381/cannot-access-jwt-claim-in-webapi-authorization-token)

Comment: github link is dead

Comment: @cuongle I know this kinda old. But when I generate token using your sample project and check to jwt.io the token is not valid. Even the sample token you provided.

Comment: Yeah, I'm noticing tokens don't always expire rightaway for a 20 second timeout. They eventually do, but I'm trying to debug timeouts in my system and they're not expiring when I tell them to. Wondering if it's what @humudu mentioned or something else.

Comment: @Humudu's comment was correct. Microsoft's library compensates by setting a ClockSkew of five minutes. Which might be fine depending on what you are implementing. You can read about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231102/812013

Comment: @Chucky: my tests show that the "default authorization" code suggested in the original code covers the case where no authorization header is provided.  In this case the response body will contain: {"Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Comment: This will always create a new token within the expiration time. Could you please help me how to create token when and only when token is expired

Comment: request.Headers.Authorization is always returning null for me can anyone help me with that.

Comment: @cuongle Great, But what if someone steals your token from the header and sends the call to API from another **source**? How will you check the incoming request is from a valid ""source or authorized source** not from the third party or **unauthorized source**?

Comment: what is the difference between this implementation (JWT) and the default web api 2.0 .net framework?

Comment: @SeanCh [Your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api#comment79321498_40284152), though [preserved on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170915060711/https://decatechlabs.com/how-to-secure-webapi-using-json-web-tokenjwt), est ded.

Comment: @ruffin sorry there were some structural changes here is the right link https://decatechlabs.com/secure-webapi-using-jwt

Comment: @ruffin Please do give feedback on article if you find any issues.  decatechlabs.com/secure-webapi-using-jwt

Comment: It allows http calls without authorization header, please accept the pull request https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt/pull/4 thanks @magicleon94

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  We're doing authentication through a 3rd-party COM-based system, but still needed to pass JWTs to the client and back.  No need for ASP.NET identity.  This was great.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidThielen et al -- you get invalid signatures at jwt.io BY DESIGN  _**because you didn't paste in his `private const string Secret` value there**_. If you go to jwt.io, cut the jwt in there by default, change the secret string from `your-256-bit-secret` to `fail` (or anything else), then paste the original back in over top of the new jwt it creates, guess what? The once valid jwt now has an Invalid signature. **Without the secret, it's [practically] impossible for someone to create jwts, _just as you want it_.** That's exactly what this stateless authentication is all about.

Comment: How would you handle JWT in a WebForms app? I'm trying to migrate a legacy system from 2005 off ClearTrust ISAP filter.

Comment: For any one who is getting unauthorized error 401 after token generation  add "config.Filters.Add(new JwtAuthenticationAttribute()); " before "config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute())"

Comment: Excellent answer. Exactly what I was looking. I've been putting off moving to .net core for years, because I couldn't find a simple replacement for OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware (which they abandoned).

Answer (score 22):

I've managed to achieve it with minimal effort (just as simple as with ASP.NET Core).

For that I use OWIN `Startup.cs` file and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` library.

In order for the app to hit `Startup.cs` we need to amend `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
    ...
```

Here's how `Startup.cs` should look:

```
using MyApp.Helpers;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.App_Start.Startup))]

namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigHelper.GetAudience(),
                        ValidIssuer = ConfigHelper.GetIssuer(),
                        IssuerSigningKey = ConfigHelper.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Many of you guys use ASP.NET Core nowadays, so as you can see it doesn't differ a lot from what we have there.

It really got me perplexed first, I was trying to implement custom providers, etc. But I didn't expect it to be so simple. `OWIN` just rocks!

Just one thing to mention - after I enabled OWIN Startup `NSWag` library stopped working for me (e.g. some of you might want to auto-generate typescript HTTP proxies for Angular app).

The solution was also very simple - I replaced `NSWag` with `Swashbuckle` and didn't have any further issues.

---

Ok, now sharing `ConfigHelper` code:

```
public class ConfigHelper
{
    public static string GetIssuer()
    {
        string result = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"];
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetAudience()
    {
        string result = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"];
        return result;
    }

    public static SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
    {
        var result = new SigningCredentials(GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetSecurityKey()
    {
        string result = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityKey"];
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] GetSymmetricSecurityKeyAsBytes()
    {
        var issuerSigningKey = GetSecurityKey();
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(issuerSigningKey);
        return data;
    }

    public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
    {
        byte[] data = GetSymmetricSecurityKeyAsBytes();
        var result = new SymmetricSecurityKey(data);
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetCorsOrigins()
    {
        string result = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsOrigins"];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Another important aspect - I sent JWT Token via **Authorization** header, so typescript code looks for me as follows:

(the code below is generated by [NSWag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nswag))

```
@Injectable()
export class TeamsServiceProxy {
    private http: HttpClient;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "https://localhost:44384";
    }

    add(input: TeamDto | null): Observable<boolean> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Teams/Add";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        const content_ = JSON.stringify(input);

        let options_ : any = {
            body: content_,
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
            })
        };
```

See headers part - `"Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')`

Comment: `I replaced NSWag with Swashbuckle and didn't have any further issues.` Does Swashbuckle have the capability to generate typescript files or is that something you added to it yourself?

Comment: @crush swashbucle is a backend library providing json, like nuget nswag library only better. In order to produce typescript file you should still use nswag package from npm.

Comment: Right, I already have swashbuckle in my project for sometime, it sounded like you were suggesting it could generate the TypeScript models instead of nswag. I'm not a fan of nswag...it's heavy. I've created my own C#->TypeScript conversion that is hooked into Swashbuckle - generates the files as a post-build process, and publishes them to an npm feed for our projects. I just wanted to make sure I hadn't overlooked a Swashbuckle project that was already doing the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a very minimal and secure implementation of a Claims based Authentication using JWT token in an ASP.NET Core Web API.

first of all, you need to expose an endpoint that returns a JWT token with claims assigned to a user:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Login provides API to verify user and returns authentication token.
        /// API Path:  api/account/login
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paramUser">Username and Password</param>
        /// <returns>{Token: [Token] }</returns>
        [HttpPost("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserRequestVM paramUser, CancellationToken ct)
        {

            var result = await UserApplication.PasswordSignInAsync(paramUser.Email, paramUser.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserRequestVM request = new UserRequestVM();
                request.Email = paramUser.Email;


                ApplicationUser UserDetails = await this.GetUserByEmail(request);
                List<ApplicationClaim> UserClaims = await this.ClaimApplication.GetListByUser(UserDetails);

                var Claims = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                                {
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, paramUser.Email.ToString()),
                                    new Claim(UserId, UserDetails.UserId.ToString())
                                });


                //Adding UserClaims to JWT claims
                foreach (var item in UserClaims)
                {
                    Claims.AddClaim(new Claim(item.ClaimCode, string.Empty));
                }

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                  // this information will be retrived from you Configuration
                //I have injected Configuration provider service into my controller
                var encryptionkey = Configuration["Jwt:Encryptionkey"];
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptionkey);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Issuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    Subject = Claims,

                // this information will be retrived from you Configuration
                //I have injected Configuration provider service into my controller
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Configuration["Jwt:ExpiryTimeInMinutes"])),

                    //algorithm to sign the token
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)

                };

                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = tokenString
                });
            }

            return BadRequest("Wrong Username or password");
        }
```

now you need to Add Authentication to your services in your `ConfigureServices` inside your **startup.cs** to add JWT authentication as your default authentication service like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
             {
                 cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 cfg.SaveToken = true;
                 cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                 {
                     //ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Encryptionkey"])),
                     ValidateAudience = false,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                     //ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                     //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Key"])),
                 };
             });
```

now you can add policies to your authorization services like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("YourPolicyNameHere",
                                policy => policy.RequireClaim("YourClaimNameHere"));
            });
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**, You can also (not necessary) populate all of your claims from your database as this will only run once on your application startup and add them to policies like this:

```
  services.AddAuthorization(async options =>
            {
                var ClaimList = await claimApplication.GetList(applicationClaim);
                foreach (var item in ClaimList)
                {                        
                    options.AddPolicy(item.ClaimCode, policy => policy.RequireClaim(item.ClaimCode));                       
                }
            });
```

now you can put the Policy filter on any of the methods that you want to be authorized like this:

```
 [HttpPost("update")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "ACC_UP")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] UserRequestVM requestVm, CancellationToken ct)
        {
//your logic goes here
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

In my case the JWT is created by a separate API so ASP.NET need only decode and validate it.   In contrast to the accepted answer we're using RSA which is a non-symmetric algorithm, so the `SymmetricSecurityKey` class mentioned above won't work.

Here's the result.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static async Task<JwtSecurityToken> VerifyAndDecodeJwt(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{securityApiOrigin}/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            var openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys,
            };
            new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out var validToken);
            // threw on invalid, so...
            return validToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use some 3d party server to support the JWT token and there is no out of the box JWT support in WEB API 2.

However there is an OWIN project for supporting some format of signed token (not JWT). It works as a reduced OAuth protocol to provide just a simple form of authentication for a web site.

You can read more about it e.g. [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

It's rather long, but most parts are details with controllers and ASP.NET Identity that you might not need at all. Most important are

> Step 9: Add support for OAuth Bearer Tokens Generation
>
> Step 12: Testing the Back-end API

There you can read how to set up endpoint (e.g. "/token") that you can access from frontend (and details on the format of the request).

Other steps provide details on how to connect that endpoint to the database, etc. and you can chose the parts that you require.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to work with weird JwtSecurityTokenHandler API

Use **JwtUtils** Nuget package with simple API

```
var claims =  new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   { "exp", 1639942616 },
   { "uname", "i.a.ivanov" },
   { "claim1", "claim1_value" },   
   { "claims_array", new [] {"claim_item1", "claim_item2"}}
};
       
string token = JWT.HS256.Create(claims, "{TOKEN_SECRET}");
```

Comment: does not work with latest framework versions

Comment: it suports netstandard2.1. What framework are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: it is not possible to port this into 4.7.2, because latest .NET Framework is 4.8 and now it move to .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code for token controller or for more details you can visit here : [How to Secure API using JWT Tokens. Building CRUD API using JWT Tokens with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core and Swagger](https://aniks.xyz/how-to-secure-api-using-jwt-tokens-building-crud-api-using-jwt-tokens-with-asp-net-core-and-entity-framework-core-and-swagger/)

From here you can learn to use JWT Token in a very easy way

```
using JWTToken.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JWTToken.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TokenController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly InventoryContext _context;

        public TokenController(IConfiguration config, InventoryContext context)
        {
            _configuration = config;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(UserInfo _userData)
        {

            if (_userData != null && _userData.Email != null && _userData.Password != null)
            {
                var user = await GetUser(_userData.Email, _userData.Password);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    //create claims details based on the user information
                    var claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                    new Claim("Id", user.UserId.ToString()),
                    new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName),
                    new Claim("LastName", user.LastName),
                    new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
                    new Claim("Email", user.Email)
                   };

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));

                    var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], _configuration["Jwt:Audience"], claims, expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), signingCredentials: signIn);

                    return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        private async Task<UserInfo> GetUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return await _context.UserInfos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
        }
    }
}
```