# Bearer Tokens in WebForms

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms, bearer-token

I have WebForms application with WebApi, without Identity provider or OAuth2. I need to implement bearer tokens for WebApi authorization, but without using Identity framework. I want to use existing custom membership provider.

I need to keep application as is with forms authentication, but to be able provide WebApi to customer mobile application. I want to return token from one WebApi method (based on provided credentials) and other application will use it to another requests.

In other words I need to authenticate mobile application in my WebApi using tokens.

How to do it in the simplest way?

Comment: Please refer my answer to use JWT token in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api/40284152#40284152

Comment: Thnx, I'll try.