# How to use JWT for asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I follow  [JWT Authentication for Asp.Net Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api) answer to add JWT to my asp.net core project but `System.Web.Http.Filters` is not supported in .net core??

any better solution for securing web API ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are supported in ASP.NET Core MVC. You can find them in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters` namespace. Take a look at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) for example.

Bear in mind that you don't need to implement JWT authentication filter yourself. This has already been implemented as part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` NuGet package. All you need is to use a JwtBearerAuthentication middleware in your app by adding `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions { /* options */ })` to `Startup.Configure()` method.