# Simple Authentication using Jwt in dot net core MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm trying to add JWT validation in my dot net core application. I've followed [this link](https://jwt.io/introduction/) to understand JWT and able to generate a token by givings some values like this.

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
  issuer: issuer,
  audience: aud,
  claims: claims,
  expires: expTime,
  signingCredentials: creds
);
```

**Edit:** and to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43699889/2660342), I've also added `JwtBearerAuthentication middleware in my app by adding app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions { /* options */ }) to Startup.Configure() method`.

Now I'm stuck how could I pass this token inside HTTP header? I'm generating this token on Login but whats next? How could I get to know that JWT is added and working fine??

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a runnable sample for bearer token authentication in ASP.NET Core.
[How to achieve a bearer token authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-a-bearer-9448db57)

At back end, you can generate the token following this code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TokenAuthController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string GetAuthToken(User user)
    {
        var existUser = UserStorage.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);

        if (existUser != null)
        {
            var requestAt = DateTime.Now;
            var expiresIn = requestAt + TokenAuthOption.ExpiresSpan;
            var token = GenerateToken(existUser, expiresIn);

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                stateCode = 1,
                requertAt = requestAt,
                expiresIn = TokenAuthOption.ExpiresSpan.TotalSeconds,
                accessToken = token
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { stateCode = -1, errors = "Username or password is invalid" });
        }
    }

    private string GenerateToken(User user, DateTime expires)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new GenericIdentity(user.Username, "TokenAuth"),
            new[] {
                new Claim("ID", user.ID.ToString())
            }
        );

        var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = TokenAuthOption.Issuer,
            Audience = TokenAuthOption.Audience,
            SigningCredentials = TokenAuthOption.SigningCredentials,
            Subject = identity,
            Expires = expires
        });
        return handler.WriteToken(securityToken);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs/ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

And add this code in Configure method

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions {
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        IssuerSigningKey = TokenAuthOption.Key,
        ValidAudience = TokenAuthOption.Audience,
        ValidIssuer = TokenAuthOption.Issuer,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
    }
});
```

At front end, you just add the token to header like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax("http://somedomain/somepath/somepage",{
    headers:{ "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
    /*some else parameter for ajax, see more you can review the Jquery API*/
});
```

Comment: from where and how I can get that accessToken??

Comment: You can find the code in Controllers/TokenAuthController.cs from the code sample.

Comment: is there any way to implement this solution through razor syntax? where we don't have ajax calls?

Comment: It's can not add the http header to the form request in browser. but you can set the token to cookie in browser, and in server side, add a middleware to set the httpheader by cookie.

Comment: maybe you should create another question for web jwt web page authentication.