# How to validate Json Web Token and extract details

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI app that's working fine with basic userid/password authentication.

However I also have to support authentication via Json Web Tokens.

Apparently the JWT will contain an encrypted userid and a signature that I will need to verify, so I assume I will have keys for that.

I don't need to create new tokens, I just need to validate them before I pass control to the usual webservice methods.
It feels like it should be simple enough, but I haven't done this before and I'm having trouble finding examples online that (a) extract the contents and validate them, and (b) do not use out-of-date libraries.

So, how do I do this, or do you know a good example online?
Thanks

Comment: You can follow up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api/40284152#40284152

Comment: That's an excellent start thanks!

Comment: @CuongLe That's a great example but it doesn't show how the filter gets the token from the header - would it be something like `token = Authorization.Parameter;`?

Comment: Yes, it is Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if is against policies to post a link as an answer but it would be easier then to extract the relevant code from it and post here
Check this [Github repo](https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt) it has everything you need to setup JWT tokes issue and validate them. Hope this help

Comment: I love that you linked to @CuongLe's repo :D