# How can I have JWT authorisation in a standalone .NET Core ASP application?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, jwt

I have been trying for weeks to implement JWT authorisation in my .NET Core web app and have found myself following a lot of guides that I don't think are relevant to my use case.  These guides talk a lot about scopes etc, and I don't think I need that level of complexity for my use case.

A lot of the guides talk about using things like OpenIddict or Identity Server to setup and configure something that the user can authorise against, but in these settings it seems like a seperate project is required to house the identity provider, and then my new asp net core application has to somehow hook into that for use.  I'm also trying to get things like refresh tokens to work so the user doesn't have to log in over and over again.

The "client side" of my app will be Xamarin (for mobile) and Angular (for web).

In a single web application (a single .net core application) how can I use .NET Core Identity with JWT or OAuth?  What is the minimum level of configuration required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This[Simple JWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api)

This is not asp.net core .This is just asp.net mvc project but this really simple and basic one. by watching this code, you will be clear how to implement JWT. Thanks