# Implementing JWT authentication Azure Function 3.x - Get Current User's Claims Using JWT token

Tags: azure, .net-core, jwt, azure-functions, claims-based-identity

I am converting dontcore web API on a new development stack to go serverless using the Azure functions.

I am thinking that my application should use Identity to store user credentials and other details. and he should get authenticated across Identity DataBase and generated using JWT tokens.

I am trying to get hold of some examples that might be helpful to see how to implement JWT in Azure functions.

JWT Token Generation Process

```cs
     public UserResponce AuthendicateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            bool valid_user= ValidateUser(username,password);
            if (vlaid_user)
            {

                // authentication successful so generate jwt token
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtIssuerOptions.Value.JwtKey);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "1"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserRoleEnum.superadmin.ToString()),
                    new Claim("hospitalid", "1")
                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwtIssuerOptions.Value.JwtExpireMinutes),
                    IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Audience = _jwtIssuerOptions.Value.JwtAuidence,
                    Issuer = _jwtIssuerOptions.Value.JwtIssuer,
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                string newJwttoken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                return new UserResponce
                {

                    //HospitalId = user.HospitalId.Value,
                    Token = newJwttoken,
                    UserId = 1,
                    UserName = username,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwtIssuerOptions.Value.JwtExpireMinutes),
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Using Functions like Bellow code, where  user, identity values getting Nulls

```cs
        var user = req.HttpContext.User;
        var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity;
```

Function Code

```cs
        [FunctionName("Get_User")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = Globals.UserRoute+"/getuser")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request started");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            AuthendicateModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthendicateModel>(requestBody);
            var user = req.HttpContext.User;
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity;
            var details = _userService.Username();
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult(new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, details, ResponseMessageEnum.Success.ToString()));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to validate. Just use this package [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize/)

In your startup class initialize authentication:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddFunctionsAuthentication();
    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
     {
        //your JWT configuration here just like in ASPNET Core
     });

builder.Services.AddFunctionsAuthorization();
```

Then all you need to do is decorate your functions or functions class with `FunctionAuthorizeAttribute` and you can have the same granular control as in ASPNET WebAPI:

```cs
    [FunctionAuthorize]
    [FunctionName("Get_User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = Globals.UserRoute+"/getuser")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {

        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request started");
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        AuthendicateModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthendicateModel>(requestBody);
        var user = req.HttpContext.User;
        var identity = user.Identity;
        var claims = user.Claims;
        var details = _userService.Username();
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return new OkObjectResult(new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, details, ResponseMessageEnum.Success.ToString()));

    }
```

Configuring authentication this way ensures tokens validation, the same way it happens in ASP.NET Core WebAPI.

You can also take a look at this [blog post](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate your jwt token in Azure function, you can use the sdk `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api)

For example

```
var authorizationHeader = req.Headers?["Authorization"];
            string[] parts = authorizationHeader?.ToString().Split(null) ?? new string[0];
            string token = string.Empty;
            if (parts.Length == 2 && parts[0].Equals("Bearer"))
                token = parts[1];
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("your jwt key vaule");
            // Validate Token and read claims

            // defile the validation Parameters according to your need
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey= new  SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };

            SecurityToken securityToken;
            try {
                // Validate Token
                ClaimsPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
                var name = principal.Identity.Name;
                log.LogInformation($"the name is {name}");
                // read claims
                foreach (var claim in principal.Claims) {
                    // process the claim
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                
                // process exception
                 
            
            }
```

[image]

Besides, if you face the issue about `Could not load file or assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` when you run the function, please add the following settings in your `.csproj` file. For further details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/397#issuecomment-596374151) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1429)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
     <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  .....
</Project>
```