# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web application - Login via xamarin

Tags: api, xamarin, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I've developed my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application with "Individual Login". Registering and logging within the app works fine.

Now I want to log in to my MVC web application with an API for my Xamarin App. From what I've read "JWT" should be used. I want to use as much "standard" in the backend as possible, ideally using standard APIs.

Unfortunately, all the sites I've tried could not help me (solution broken, non-existing urls,....).

Could somebody please post me a working tutorial or an example for the backend please.

Thanks, Jeppen

Comment: This helped a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From api, you can configure the jwt authentication as this.

1. In `Startup`

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {

            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

                //The previous three items are required
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                ValidAudience = "api",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is a long key"))

                /***********************************default TokenValidationParameters parameter***********************************/
                // RequireSignedTokens = true,
                // SaveSigninToken = false,
                // ValidateActor = false,

            };

        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        //...
    }
   ```
2. Apply for a token, generate a string token in the action.

   ```
    public IActionResult Authenticate()
    {

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is a long key");
        var authTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var expiresAt = authTime.AddDays(7);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Audience,"api"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Issuer,"http://localhost:5000"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Id, "10"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "my name"),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "email"),
            }),
            Expires = expiresAt,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return Ok(tokenString);
    }
   ```
3. Xamarin App receives token and save it. When Xamarin App access the authorized resource, it can carray this token with this `header`.

   ```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var token = client.GetAsync("[url that get the token] ");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        client.GetAsync("[url that get the authorized resource] ");
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first time my app is creating a token. But when I run my site, I get a blank page. In the developper tools, I get a 401 Unauthorized. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Make sure that configuration in the startup is the same as the configuration of the token (Audience, Issuer, IssuerSigningKey).