# Jwt token support in Microsoft IIs as a module without writing code

Tags: iis

Is there a module to support JWT in Microsoft IIS similar to Apache's mod_Authnz_jwt

I have static web pages I would like to secure with JWT

Comment: IIS has no built-in support for that. You might search for third party module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS doesn't have a module to support JWT. But JWT can be set in asp.net application. It depends on System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api) about how to configure JWT on asp.net application.

Though you cannot use JWT to secure static page, IIS has a module called Authentication to secure site. You can enable it to protect pages.
[image]