# How to authenticate the JWT sent from the Microsoft Teams MessageCard HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

Using Microsoft Teams MessageCard, I am able to utilize the HttpPost to send data to a service, but how do I authenticate the JWT with Azure Active Directory that is sent in the Authorization header?  I know the JWT contains the logged-in AD user object id, but I cannot find any documentation on what to do once I have the value(s).

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-in-node-web-app-with-api) and let us know if that helps?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT  Not really.  The authentication is failing, but nothing is logged or any type of error as to why.  Is it the JWT? Did I misspell something?  Have an extra slash? Who knows?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hello @Kevin - Could you please elaborate more on service? Is it your custom service or any other, please share more information.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft It is an internal/custom ASP.Net Core 8.0 plain ol' service with no fancy widgets or gizmos.

Comment: Looks like your query is more related to how to authenticate JWT token in .net core side but not related to Teams application. Please refer this thread once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @ChetanSharma I know how to authenticate a JWT internally (we're doing it now), that's not the problem. I have a the JWT from Microsoft Teams, how do I authenticate it in Azure?

Comment: Hello @KevinRF - Could you please let us know how you are trying to authenticate in Azure? Are you talking about deployed service or something else?

Comment: Please refer this documentation as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow