How to add JWT token in startup.cs to work for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API using C#?
I have a legacy project I am working on and its using ASP.NET Web API for REST API, and not Core. And I can't change it to .NET Core for reasons I can't say.
My problem is I want to implement JWT for security, and I can't find a single working example for JWT and ASP.NET REST API that is not using .NET Core.
I would love if some one can share a full working solution for this.
I would love if I can use the [Authorize] attribute on top of the controller methods for direct authentication, also if I can authorize by role or claims sent inside the JWT .
Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks
I know how to create the token, and how to create a function to validate it, but in a manual way. But I would love to use the power of attributes

If you search for asp.net API + JWT in SO, you will find several well detailed answers with examples of what you are looking for. For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api As a side note, if you want to learn coding pattern for an older version (as you mentioned), it might help to peruse through some OpenSource Github projects.

thanks @sandiejat, i have been search in google for the last couple of days , and i didn't find anything like the one you sent, i will use the search string you sent and search in SO , and i don't want to sound lazy , cause i am really looking , but if you happen to pass by any of those well detailed examples , it would be nice if you can share the links , this will be highly appreciated , thanks again
